# NullPointerException on android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatBase$Action.getIcon()

Tags: android, kotlin, android-notifications, kotlin-android-extensions

anyone can help?
Code `mBuilder.build` produces crash

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatBase$Action.getIcon()' on a null object reference
```

Here is my code

```
private fun createNotification(pushMessage: FirebaseMessage){
        Timber.d("Firebase")
        // create notification builder
        var mBuilder: NotificationCompat.Builder = if(SystemTools.isAtLeastOreo())
            NotificationCompat.Builder(this, getChannelId(pushMessage))
        else
            NotificationCompat.Builder(this)

        val inboxStyle = NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                .setBigContentTitle(pushMessage.title)
                .bigText(pushMessage.message)

        // create notification view
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_car) // have to use jpeg or png for notification icon (crash)
//                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(baseContext.resources, R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round))
                .setColor(ResourceUtils.getColor(baseContext, R.color.teal))
                .setContentTitle(pushMessage.title)
                .setContentText(pushMessage.message)
                .setStyle(inboxStyle)
                .setContentIntent(getPendingIntent(pushMessage))
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .addAction(createNotificationAction(pushMessage))
                .setBadgeIconType(R.drawable.ic_notification_car)


        // send notification
        sendNotification(mBuilder.build())
    }
```

`supportLibrary = '26.1.0'`
`playServices = '11.4.0'`

**SOLUTION:**

- As exception said: `Action.getIcon()` NullPointerException

I've created usecase `.addAction(createNotificationAction(pushMessage))`
which generated appropriate action depending on `pushMessage: FirebaseMessage`.
In case that pushMessage didn't match anything i returned null. That was causing exception. So basically you cannot put to `NotificationBuilder.addAction(null)`

***Question may be closed***

Comment: can you post the complete stack trace ?

Comment: Please add more code and line where this exception occured !!

Comment: As the others said, please show us which line is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Wrong use of [setBadgeIconType](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setBadgeIconType(int))

Sets which `icon` to display as a `badge` for this `notification`. Must be one of **`BADGE_ICON_NONE`**, **`BADGE_ICON_SMALL`**, **`BADGE_ICON_LARGE`**.

**Note**: This value might be ignored, for launchers that don't support badge icons.